# IoT Agents - NGSI 10 Only (No NGSI 9)?

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

from what I can see here: https://github.com/telefonicaid/iotagent-node-lib/blob/master/lib/services/ngsi/ngsiService.js in the `createRequestObject` only `/updateContext` and `/queryContext` are used - so, ONLY NGSI 10 API.

Is NGSI 9 ever used in IoT Agents, and how?

I am surprised, because I expected that registering of device will call NGSI 9 `registerContext`, but this is not the case, and only NGSI 10 `/updateContext` is called.

BR,

Drasko

Answer (score 0):

Agents use both NGSI 10 and NGSI 9, but they do not accept NGSI 9 requests. I.e.: Agents work as Context Providers when you define lazy attributes or commands, registering themselves with NGSI 9 in the Context Broker; being Context Providers, they must accept NGSI 10 requests (not NGSI 9), in order for the Context Broker to compose the response to a third party context request. All this behavior is explained with sequence diagrams in the IoTAgent Node.js library: https://github.com/telefonicaid/iotagent-node-lib#device-to-ngsi-mapping. In those diagrams you can see how the IoT Agents send registerContext requests for their lazy/command attributes.

On the other side, IOTAs do not accept NGSI requests, as they don't perform context request redirections (as a Orion do), for the IoT Agents are Context Providers, not Context Brokers.

Comment: "Agents work as Context Providers when you define lazy attributes or commands, registering themselves with NGSI 9 in the Context Broker;" - can you please point me to the code for this registration? Where exactly do we send NGSI 9 Registration requests in the code of `iotagent-node-lib`, because I can not find them - all I see are NGSI 10 requests (update, query and subscribe).

Comment: And by the way - what is the difference between `Register Device` and `Lazy Attributes` in the sense of NGSI 9? I can see that they both send `/registerContext`. I.e. does `Regitesr Device` also calls NGSI 9 of Orion and registers device as a Context Provider (even if we never use Lazy Attributes, i.e. if device is only active provider, sends updates by itself for example every 5 minutes).

Comment: Concerning the NGSI9 code, you can find it here:

https://github.com/telefonicaid/iotagent-node-lib/blob/master/lib/services/devices/registrationUtils.js

You can trace where it is invoked from there (in the provision of devices mainly). Concerning your next question, I don't follow what you are talking about. Lazy attributes are one of the three types of attributes available, while RegisterDevice is the process of creating a device and its initial entity in the agent. It should register the IOTA as context provider if there are any lazy attributes or commands. Otherwise, we have a bug.